# Are there birds with knees instead of elbows?

Tags: ornithology, joints

Are there any birds whose legs fold the same way human legs do, in a knee, instead of an elbow which is what all the birds I know have?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The joint you are thinking of is not a [knee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knee), nor is it an [elbow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow), instead it is an [ankle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ankle) which is bending the same way as us humans. You can see from the below diagram that the knee - the joint between the femur and tibia - is just further up the leg normally hidden by feathers.

Birds have a comparatively elongated metatarsus which gives the impression that the knee bends backwards more like an elbow, but it's just the ankle. ([Image from here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Anatomy_and_Physiology_of_Animals/The_Skeleton))

[image]

I also liked this diagram from a [blogpost](http://skeletaldrawing.blogspot.se/2011/09/um-hey-scientific-american-bird-knees.html) on a similar theme...
[image]

To follow up there appears to be no animals whose ankles bend the "wrong" way.

http://www.answers.com/Q/Which_animal_has_backward_knees

http://qi.com/infocloud/knees

http://www.ehow.com/info_12317202_birds-knees-backwards.html#page=1

Though these are far from conclusive resources. I'd guess the way knee is defined (it means something to humans but not to nature (a bit like the species being a concept which has weak biological bounds)) has something to do with that

Comment: Good point, thank you! It didn't occur to me. However, the joint I'm talking about is between Tibia and Metatarsus (ankle, right)? Are there any birds whose ankles bend backwards?

Comment: according to the blogpost mentioned above no, no tetrapods do this

Comment: @violetgirraffe edits made

Comment: +1 Nice answer. You should add a reference to the first figure thought.

Comment: Did you replace the first illustration? You shouldn't have, the other one was much larger and clearer; I can hardly read anything on this one.